# C++: when object constructed in argument is destructed?

Tags: c++

When object constructed in argument is destructed, before of after function call?

E.g. is the following code safe?

```
void f(const char*)
{ ... }

std::string g()
{ ... }
...
f(g().c_str());
```

It always works for me but I don't know is it just undefined behaviour or it actually should work.

Comment: instead of using g().data() use g().c_str(), just an idea... <- Ignore that (for your question, still good practice), your code is safe IF you are not returning a reference or pointer

Comment: @jamolnng That makes no difference to the question at hand.

Comment: I realized that afterwards, which is where I corrected it to add pertinent information

Comment: @jamolnng I fixed it, data() has no null-terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g()` is a temporary. Lifetime of tempraries extends for the entire time of evaluation of the entire *full-expression* (in your case, that would be `f(g().c_str())`) Therefore your usage is safe, unless the `f()` stores the pointer somewhere.

> §12.2/4 There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression. The first context is when an expression appears as an initializer for a declarator defining an object. In that context, the temporary that holds the result of the expression shall persist until the object’s initialization is complete. [...]
>
> §12.2/5 The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. [...]

Neither of these two cases apply in your example.

Comment: is this correct citation and not 12.3/3 should be cited?

Comment: @bits_international I believe your citation is better, because it confirms the temporary lifetime directly, while mine only indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

> It always works for me but I don't know is it just undefined behaviour
>   or it actually should work.

No, there is no undefined behavior because temporary object produced by g() will be deleted after evaluating full expression, that is body of f() function.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 12.3/3

When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that has a non-trivial constructor (12.1,
12.8), it shall ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object. Similarly, the destructor shall be
called for a temporary with a non-trivial destructor (12.4). Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step
in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true
even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects of destroying

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 12.3/4

There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-
expression. The first context is when a default constructor is called to initialize an element of an array. If
the constructor has one or more default arguments, the destruction of every temporary created in a default
argument is sequenced before the construction of the next array element, if any.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 12.3/5

The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. (...)

Comment: No, it's no undefined behavior. The local `std::string` returned by `g()` is destructed after the full expression is evaluated. That means it's not destructed until *after* the function has been called.

Comment: @0x499602D2 do you mean temporary returned by g()?

Answer (score 2):

A temporary object constructed as part of an expression evaluation is destructed after evaluating the *full expression* containing the expression, unless it is bound to a named reference. (12.2 and 1.9 in the current draft standard are the relevant sections).

So in your example, the temporary constructed to hold the return value of `g` will be destroyed after `f` returns.